# How to reconfigure gmail in Outlook after setting up 2FA?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, two-factor-authentication, microsoft-outlook-2019, multi-factor-authentication

On May 30, 2022 Google blocked Outlook from being able to connect to Gmail accounts unless 2FA is enabled. So I have enabled 2FA just now on my gmail account, and my Outlook-connected gmail account still won't connect via Outlook. I'm pretty sure I have to remove my gmail account from outlook and then re-add it, at which time 2FA will kick in. But if I remove my gmail account from Outlook I'm afraid all my emails will be deleted and gone forever.

How can I reconnect my gmail account to Outlook to take advantage of 2FA without losing all my emails?

Note: I have long since had a setting in my gmail account that after a mail client downloads an email it should be deleted from the server. Yes, that is how I want it - I never use the gmail web client, I use Outlook. So all my gmail emails have been downloaded to Outlook (except for the past few days when Outlook can no longer connect to my gmail). So I really don't want to lose those download emails, especially since they've already been deleted from the gmail server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internet is abuzz with this.

You are right that the first step is to activate 2FA in your Google account.

But there is still a second step. You have to generate a 16-character app password for Mail in your Google account. Go to Gmail -> Google Account -> Security -> Signing in to Google -> App passwords -> select pulldowns, click Generate. REPLACE your gmail password in Outlook with that generated password.

Then everything will be back to normal.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you Keith, that worked great. I wonder if you might update your answer with more detailed instructions to help others. Go to Gmail -> Google Account -> Security -> Signing in to Google -> App passwords -> select pulldowns, click Generate. REPLACE your gmail password in Outlook with that generated password.

Comment: You've just done it for me! Glad that helped.